# Adding point at the beginning of call out line

Tags: qgis, point, line, geometry-generator

I am trying to add a point at the start of my callout lines in QGIS but I don't manage.

I create an additional geometry generator to my callout line and use this code:

```py
make_point(closest_point($geometry, make_point("X_Core", "Y_Core")))
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: X_Core and Y_Core are the fields of my moved label

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't use `start_point`?

Answer (score 1):

I need to remove `make_point`!

```
closest_point($geometry, make_point( "X_Core" , "Y_Core"  ))
```